# python read controller button's velocity

Tags: python, pygame, joystick

i need to get a joystick's velocity data, but pygame (also my os) only tells me if a button on a specified controller is pressed or else..

i'm trying to convert guitar hero drum controller signals into midi, the controller is seen by the os as a normal joystick and the pads are buttons. i know for sure that the controller sends out informations about the velocity at wich a button is pressed but i cannot find a way to get that info.

i'm writing my "translator" in python, but it's not a big piece of code so i can easily switch to another language that provides me the right libraries, is there a way to get the buttons' velocities?

Comment: What do you mean by "the velocity at which a button is pressed"?  Unless the buttons are pressure sensitive (can tell if you're pressing them halfway or all the way), then I don't think there's any way to find that information, the button is either pressed, or it isn't.

Comment: the buttons ARE pressure sensitive, it's like ps2 controller, it has pressure sensors on the four main buttons (cross, square, circle, triangle) and the os does recognize the drum like a normal joystick, but i cant find how to read the pressure value, it only tells me if the buttons are pressed or not.

Comment: Supposedly SDL (which Pygame is largely a Python wrapper for) does not support pressure sensitive buttons. http://lists.libsdl.org/pipermail/sdl-libsdl.org/2005-December/053104.html

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/show_file.php?file=move_game_controller.py) on a site i used to use.

Using horiz_axis_pos= my_joystick.get_axis(0) and vert_axis_pos= my_joystick.get_axis(1) , i think you can read the velocity, because it reads both horizontal and vertical velocity, which you can get an angle from.

Try it! (Honestly, this seemed to work for me, but idk for you)

Comment: Does SDL register pressure sensitive buttons as axes?

Comment: @Haz you can get where the pressure is on both axises, so you can get the angle and position from that

Comment: @PythonInProgress but axes are not buttons! i need the velocity info of buttons, i don't think i can "cast" a joystick.button to joystick.axis and then read the pressure..or can i?
(reguar ps2 controller buttons with pressure sensivity are registered as button, only the analog sticks are registered as axes)

Comment: @mellotanica you've stumped me :P try it tho

Comment: PythonInProgress, nope, there's nothing i can do.. there is no button class or axis class to cast somthing to, and most probably it's this way because pygame is an SDL wrapper (as @Haz commented).. i need another library / language i think..